# YouCompleteMe and clang-tidy

Tags: vim, youcompleteme

When building YouCompleteMe, there is an option to `USE_CLANG_TIDY`, which seems to be off by default (at least when building on Linux).  What is the benefit to turning it on?

Answer (score 3):

I got curious after seeing `--clang-tidy` flag in installer options as well. Here is what I found going through YCM's git history:

- [This](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/commit/2ad0cfc0d8123ca7d3487b2b1d00568f3ffc5334) is the commit where this feature was merged to YouCompleteMe from ycmd (YCM's backend).
- [This](https://github.com/Valloric/ycmd/pull/1033) is the corresponding pull request and discussion in ycmd. One of developers [says](https://github.com/Valloric/ycmd/pull/1033#issuecomment-390399656):

> i feel like we should only be running clang-tidy when developing, not when building for users.

So, this feature isn't intended for users of the plugin, but rather for developers of the plugin.

---

**TL;DR:** There is no benefit to turning it on from end-user perspective.